# Multi-threading Report Progress Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, backgroundworker

I've recently started working with multi-threaded Winform applications and have run up against a problem I don't understand.

Basically, when I try to have a background worker report its progress and that progress comes from a calculation, it is always zero.

```
//making background worker
        BackgroundWorker myJanitor = new BackgroundWorker();
        myJanitor.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        myJanitor.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        myJanitor.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(cleanContactList);
        myJanitor.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(myCleaningWorker_ProgressChanged);
        myJanitor.RunWorkerAsync();
```

The 'cleanContactList' method loops through a DataGridView's rows, during which I try something like this:

```
int percentComplete = (myRow.Index  / contactGridView.Rows .Count ) * 100;                       
(sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(percentComplete);
```

Frustratingly, percentComplete will ALWAYS be zero. If I debug it I can see that there is an actual calculation occurring (e.g. [2000/10000]*100) but the result is always zero.

What am I missing here? If I replace the calculation with, say, a Random.Next(0,100) call it updates fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try index * 100/count.  I think you're dividing two ints leading to 0 then multiplying by 100.

For example, this:

```
        int index = 50;
        int count = 100;

        int percent = index/count * 100;
        int percent2 = index * 100/count;

        Console.WriteLine("{0} & {1}", percent, percent2);
```

Outputs 0 & 50.

Comment: Well, that was an easy one. Thanks!

Comment: I had to wait 8 minutes before it'd let me :)

Comment: Oh - didn't remember that :)  Thanks.  Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

> [2000/10000]*100) but the result is always zero

C# 101 for beginners. Actually more programming - it is the same in most languages that know variable types.

Operations happen on the alrgest most precice variable type involved.

2000 (integer) / 10000 (integer) is aninteger result rounded = 0

I suggest you FIRST multiply, THEN divide. Or choose a different variable type either in the variables, or in the formula (i.e. [(float)2000 will convert the whole formulat to use floats.